# Why are some rigidbodies falling through passive objects and others are not?

Tags: mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I've been trying to simulate a chain falling onto a platform, but after I've applied active rigidbody modifiers to all links of the chain, and applying a passive rigidbody modifier to the mesh below, all of the links still fall through, with only one of the hands remaining on top of the mesh(even though the hand has the same modifiers as all the other objects).

Any solutions to this problem? I've tried increasing the the steps per second and resetting all the modifiers. Here are some photos of whats happening.

[image: Object before simulation]

[image: Object falling through during simulation]

[image: Everything falling through except for one hand for some reason]